# How do I create a redistributable RPM for Mono.Fuse?

Tags: mono, rpm, fuse, opensuse

First, I obviously *tried* to get a binary release of [Mono.Fuse](http://www.jprl.com/Projects/mono-fuse/) project, but the only available downloads were the source files. (And actually it seems that latest release has a syntax error in an override)

So I tried to install it on a Linux box from git, successfully, but I'll soon need to bring it to a production server together with my Xcopy-deployable application.

I don't like compiling software on a production machine, especially because I need to install loooooooooooots of development tools from YaST. So now I have this git-cloned directory with all source and compiled files.

How can I create an RPM package that I can install on multiple production machines with a simple command without resolving `configure.sh`'s dependencies with lots of unneeded libraries like glib-2.0-devel?

Comment: did you ever succeed with this? i am having a similar problem but i can't build in my case so needing to build elsewhere or download.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Open Build Service](http://openbuildservice.org/).